# In what way do developed countries drain trillions of dollars from developing countries?

Tags: economics, sociology

**On the advice of the monitors, I have [reposted](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56789/in-what-way-do-developed-countries-steal-trillions-of-dollars-from-developing-co) this question on Economics SE.**

According to [the Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/2017/jan/14/aid-in-reverse-how-poor-countries-develop-rich-countries), rich Western countries drain large amounts of money from poor countries, much more than they give in development aid.

> If we add theft through trade in services to the mix, it brings total net resource outflows to about $3tn per year.
> That’s 24 times more than the aid budget. In other words, for every $1 of aid that developing countries receive, they lose $24 in net outflows. These outflows strip developing countries of an important source of revenue and finance for development. The GFI report finds that increasingly large net outflows have caused economic growth rates in developing countries to decline, and are directly responsible for falling living standards.

[Aljazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/amp/opinions/2021/5/6/rich-countries-drained-152tn-from-the-global-south-since-1960) gives a similar statement.

I would like to know in what way the money is ‘drained’, if this is illegal and if this is indeed ‘directly responsible for falling living standards’.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149201/discussion-on-question-by-riemann-do-developed-countries-drain-trillions-of-doll); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Why was this closed? Seems like a reasonable question

Comment: @CJR: see chat.

Comment: @CJR: I explain [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64599402#64599402) starting "I closed the question because it seems to conflate several concepts (as does the original article)."

Comment: I edited the question. Now it is not focused on if money is drained, but instead on the matter wherein money is drained.

Comment: That looks like an answer, not a reason to close the question.

Comment: @Riemann, but now it's a "Explain" rather than a "True/False" question, which would be more suitable for this site. The answer would be something like "As stated in the cited articles, which are confusing and self-contradictory, there is no reason to believe the claims.".

Comment: I will respond in chat.

Comment: @Oddthinking: yeah, I agree, the 'in what way' is not a suitable Q here. Econ SE is [that way](https://economics.stackexchange.com/). The paper is probably fringe and tendinous in the way uses some terms, but it would probably take something that passes for 'original research' here to attack/answer it like that. Econ SE has fewer limitations on what answers can contain. See similar issue with another Q here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56154/does-breaking-rsa-really-require-20-million-qubits